# Powerpress upload a podcast without creating a post for it

Tags: plugins, posts, pages, uploads, podcasting

Hi Im trying to upload a podcast using PowerPress but without creating a post for it on website as the podcast will be listened to using podcast.player. I don't mind creating the page as private but I don't want to post a single page every podcast episode.

Comment: I don't know PowerPress but you will need to make something for the podcast that will appear in the podcast RSS feed. Maybe that can be a different post type that still includes the podcast attributes, or maybe it's a regular post that you exclude from the UI - but not the feed - somehow.

Comment: This is really a question for the developers of PowerPress, but if you want to create a podcast feed _without_ blog posts, then WordPress probably isn't the right tool. There are dedicated podcast services for that sort of thing.